# Building dynamic SQL queries

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, design-patterns

I've a database that looks like this -

```
I have an excel file that look like this - 

Ticket #      Status      Person     Department
1.            Open        John       Support
2.            Working     Mark       Engineering
3.            Pending     Betty      Support
4.            Working     Mark       Engineering
5.            Open        Mark       Support
6.            Open        John       Engineering
7.            Pending     Betty      Support 
8.            Working     John       Support
9.            Working     Mark       Support 
10.           Pending     Betty      Engineering
```

I'm making a swing application which lists information like this -

Problem 1. How many tickets under [Person Name 1 (Eg. Mark)] are open/working/closed.

Problem 2. How many tickets under [Person Name 1 (Eg. Mark)] belong to Support/Engineering department.

In the application, a user is supposed to select the name of the person from a JCombobox.
Also, I'm using JFreeChart to list the results which I've got handled already.

My question -

For Problem 1. following query works for me -

```
Select Status, count(status) 
from [table name] 
where Person=Mark 
group by status
```

But I want my application to build this query by itself, i.e. I want it to populate "Mark" by itself [user will select the Person in the JCombobox].

Similarly I want the application to build the following query by itself if the user selects to list the department (instead of status) of a ticket by the person name

```
Select department, count(department) 
from [table name] 
where Person=John 
group by department
```

NOTE - User will select the Person name and the function [status or department] from 2 Jcombobox drop downs.

Update - TO make it more clear

I want my query to have a "Person=?" instead of "Person=Mark". So that, the application reads "Mark" in the database, and then populates "Person=?" with "Person=Mark".

Comment: "But I want my application to build this query by itself, i.e. I want it to populate "Mark" by itself [user will select the Person in the JCombobox]." This is not a question. What do you need from us?

Comment: Use prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Prepared statements are definitely the way to go. They will protect against SQL injection, and do exactly what you require. You build the statement using the sentinel '?' character for where variable data will go, and you set the value at the index of the ? using one of several methods PreparedStatement exposes.

Comment: @jwatkins I want my query to have a "Person=?" instead of "Person=Mark". So that, the application reads "Mark" in the database, and then populates "Person=?" with "Person=Mark". Does that make it more clear?